# Manipular arquivos de texto em python

Tags: python

Sei que não é possível escrever em um arquivo que eu abro em modo leitura, mas queria saber se é possível ler as linhas de um arquivo que eu abro pra escrita, **depois de ter escrito nele**?

Answer (score 1):

O arquivo precisa ser aberto usando o modo `wr+`, o que permite operações de leitura e gravação por meio do descritor do arquivo,

Você pode usar o método `seek()` do descritor para voltar o cursor do arquivo para o inicio, veja só:

```
lista = ['alpha','beta','gamma','delta']

with open("texto.txt", "wr+") as arq:

    # Grava cada elemento da lista como uma linha no arquivo
    for i in lista:
        arq.write(i + "\n" )

    # Retorna cursosr para o inicio do arquivo
    arq.seek( 0, 0 )

    # Le as linhas do arquivo a partir do
    for linha in arq:
        print(linha.strip())
```

Saída:

```
alpha
beta
gamma
delta
```